# export large list<> to excel C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, datagrid

I want to export a list with over 10000 rows to excel using MVC5 C#.

1. when I export using `DataGrid` some columns are not shown in the excel file - 3 columns are disapeard in the excel file but all the 10000 rows appeard.

```
    


    string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + ".xls";
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
    DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid(); 
    List registrationsetList = db.RegistrationSet.Where(x => x.QuestionId == TheQuestion.Id).ToList();
    dgGrid.DataSource = registrationsetList;
    dgGrid.DataBind();
    dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);

    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

2. If I change

   ```
   DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid()
   ```

   to

   ```
   GridView dgGrid = new GridView();
   ```

   with list of 600 of rows, the excel looks perfect with all the columns.
   **the problem is when i export all the list of 10000 rows, the excel file got stuck - i got not responding message.
   why ?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a DataGrid() try using a WebControl GridView():

```
string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + ".xls";
var gv = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
var registrationsetList = db.RegistrationSet.Where(x => x.QuestionId == TheQuestion.Id);
g.DataSource = registrationsetList;
gv.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = "";
StringWiter sw = new StringWriter();
var htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: This is what I did, the file saved, and then when i open it it stucked - i got a message not responding

Answer (score 0):

The problem (with that stucked excel file) was solved with  `DataGrid`. The problem was that the `DateGrid` doen't show columns of nullable fields in the CLASS in the list that i bound to the `GridView`.